# Считывание с doc или docx

Tags: c#

Прошу вас помочь с считыванием (записью) информации с 'doc' или 'docx' файла на C# и выводом всей информации на консоль.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

[Примеры для Office 2010](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/OfficeDevFuture/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ru-RU#1)

[Программирование приложений Office C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee342218.aspx)

Общий вид

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; 
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

Word.Application MSWord = new Word.Application();

            try
            {
                Word.Document Doc = MSWord.Documents.Open(...);

                foreach (Word.Table WordTable in Doc.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (Word.Row WordRow in WordTable.Rows)
                    {                        
                        foreach (Word.Cell WordCell in WordRow.Cells)
                        {                            
                             ...  
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
            catch
            {
                ...
            }
```

Comment: какаую библиотеку надо подключить ??? подскажи пожалуйста  . . .

Comment: Нужно добавить ссылку на Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word и Microsoft.Office.Core

Если их нет в списке, то установите 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508